# Number alerts in Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, prompt, alerts

How to decide number of alerts popping up, depending on the input from user?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the user would want to see multiple alerts, but try:

```
let number = prompt("Write a number");
for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
  alert(i);
}
```

You would still need to check that `number` is a valid number before running the `for(..)` loop.  Also note that some browsers allow users the choice of hiding multiple alerts.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will trigger X alerts from a prompt input

```js
let number = prompt("Write a number");
for (var i = 0; i< parseInt(number); i++){
  alert('hey '+i+1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let number = prompt("Write a number");
for (var i = 0; i< parseInt(number); i++){
  alert('hey '+i+1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd only like to add that you need to add the Number function in the alert prompt or else it will consider it like a string.

```
let number = prompt("Write a number");
for (let i = 0; i< parseInt(number); i++){
   alert('hey ' + Number(i + 1));
}
```